# secure websocket client connects from a server side client but not from browser client

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ubuntu, websocket, tornado

I am having trouble connecting via wss WebSocket from a browser (react js) to tornado WebSocket server.

If I connect server-side from a python WebSocket client it interacts with the tornado server successfully, but using the exact same URL/endpoint from the browser does not work.

The browser code also works in a non-secure environment. The browser client is in react and the actual socket connection just uses vanilla javascript WebSocket.
Server (tornado configuration):

```
import os
import tornado.escape
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import config
import logging
import logging.config
from alive.webserver import SocketHandler
from proc_manager import ProcManager
from tornado.options import define, options
#define("debug", default=True, help="Debug settings")
define("port", default=48939, help="Port to run the server on")


def main():
    settings = {}
    proc_man = ProcManager()
    urls = [(r"/ws/processor$", SocketHandler, dict(proc_man=proc_man, sub_callback='run_status'))]
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    # Create Tornado application
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        urls,
        **settings)

    # Start Server
    logging.info("Starting App with Debug Mode")

    if config.ssl_options:
        logging.info(f'App listening on secure connection {options.port}')
        app.listen(options.port, ssl_options=config.ssl_options)

    logging.info(f'listening on insecure connection {48938}')
    app.listen(48938)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

config file (imported above):

```
ssl_options = {
    'certfile': '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem',
    'keyfile': '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem'
}
```

JS websocket client code:

```
export class WebSock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    // console.log(window.location.host)
    // console.log(window.location.hostname)
    this.wsURL =
      (document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss://" : "ws://") +
      window.location.hostname +
      ":" +
      (document.location.protocol === "https:"
        ? props.port[1]
        : props.port[0]) +
      "/" +
      props.endpoint;
    this.connected = false;
    this.socket = null;
    this.reconnect = props.reconnect !== undefined ? props.reconnect : true;
    this.socket = null;
    this.initSock()
  }


  newConn = (e) => {
    if (this.socket) {
      while (!this.socket.CLOSED) {
        if (!this.socket.CLOSING) {
          this.socket.close();
        }
      }
      delete this.socket;
      this.socket = null;
    }
    console.log(this.wsURL);
    this.socket = new WebSocket(this.wsURL);

    //override from child class
  };


  sub = (d) => {
    // console.log(d)
  };
  sendMessage = (data) => {
    this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    // console.log(data);
  };
 initSock = (e) => {
    this.newConn();
    this.socket.onclose = (e) => {
      this.connected = false;
      // console.log('Disconnected')
      if (this.reconnect) {
        this.sleep(1000);
        this.initSock();
      }
    };

    this.socket.onerror = (error) => {
      // console.log('on error',error)
      // console.log(error)
    };
    this.socket.onopen = (e) => {
      this.connected = true;
      console.log("Connected");
      this.sendMessage({
        method: "sub",
        args: {
          channels: "reporting",
          user: window.user_name,
        },
      });
    };
    this.socket.onmessage = (d) => {
      const msg = JSON.parse(d.data);
      // console.log(msg)
      if (msg.success) {
        this[msg.method](msg);
        return false;
      } else {
        // console.log(msg)
      }
    };
  };


}
```

Chrome error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.com:48939/ws/processor' failed: 
WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

Firefox error:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://mysite.com:48939/ws/processor
```

When I print the URL produced by the javascript client above it yields: `wss://mysite.com:48939/ws/processor`

- I have a valid SSL cert for mysite.com using letsencyrpt
- The server is ubuntu 18.0.4
- The same endpoint as above works if I call it from a python client on the server-side.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "window.location.hostname" wouldn't the client's hostname be different than the server you need to connect to?

Comment: Yes I wondered about about that. After console.logging the connection string, the window.location.hostname is printing the the domain name of the website. Which is the same server as where the webscoket server resides.

Comment: Alright I figured this one out. The code and configuration is correct (well apart from lousy coding). I was managing the firewall for the vps instance using ufw, and was unaware that My Client's hosting provider has a seperate firewall enabled in their Control panels that blocks most ports by default. Once I enabled the port there it started working.